# Archiving the application gives error about certificates, but I think I added certificates correctly

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning

I am trying to archive a new app, but when I do that I get this error:

```
Code Sign error: Provisioning profile 'BusinessIdeaLive' specifies the Application Identifier 'com.problemio.businessidea' which doesn't match the current setting '4MS3885ZWL.com.problemio.businessidea'
```

So I understand that there is a mis-match of '4MS3885ZWL.com.problemio.businessidea' and com.problemio.businessidea

But in the certificates I made, and my plist I have the '4MS3885ZWL.com.problemio.businessidea' so I am not sure why this error is happening.  Any idea why the error occurs and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: not a solution, more like a ritual to pacify the XCode demons: Restart xcode, clean target, delete derived data, archive.

Comment: @calvinBhai doing this now :)

Comment: By the way, how do I delete derived data?

Comment: goto organizer (on your XCode, top right corner button), select the Projects tab on top, and then on the left bar, select the current open project. On the right side section, you can see an option to delete the derived data.

Comment: You can also hold down the Option key, and the Clean menu changes to Clean Build Folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist should only contain "com.problemio.businessidea", without the 4MS3885ZWL prefix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I restarted the xCode.
Selected proper provisional profile in both target and build settings and archived again solved the problem.

Comment: Thank you! Let me try that now. By the way, what do you mean by selected proper provisional profile in target and build settings? Just so I don't get it wrong, what is the right way to do this?